# Cannot Remove Housing on Westmore Lighting Coventry 8.4-in W Hazelnut Bronze Outdoor Flush Mount Light

Tags: light-fixture

[image]I purchased this light fixture from Lowe's and had it installed.  It's time to change the bulb.  I removed both the screws but the housing will not come off.  I've pulled on it but it won't budge.  I don't want to break it. I would insert a picture but I'm not sure that's an option here.  Here is the link to Lowes: https://www.lowes.com/pd/Westmore-Lighting-Coventry-8-4-in-W-Hazelnut-Bronze-Outdoor-Flush-Mount-Light/1002865848

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The only documentation on Lowes' is the super-important Prop65 Warning Label :-)

Comment: I would guess there is a gasket and it has glue the pieces together.  Light taps with a rubber mallet or a piece of wood wrapped with a cloth might loosen it.  Can also try an old thin knife/screwdriver to try to ply it loose.

Comment: It wont let me open the link. When editing  press on the square icon with mountains on it, to add pictured.

Comment: No chance you can just push up the bottom pane of glass?